# Visa Rejection Status

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

My application has been rejected in 2018 to visit uk. I applyied again in 2019 to study at university and granted the visa and travelled to uk. In first week before applying for the BRP, i have been informed that i had to go back to my country due to some family issue and i did. Does my reject will remain or my visit to the uk and cancelling the study before issuance of BRP will ignore the reject from uk immigration system.
My passport has a vignette sticker and the visa granted is D-TIER 4.
Regards.

Comment: If you suspended your studies for more than 60 days, you should have received notification from UKVI that your visa was curtailed (cancelled) Rules 323A (ii) 2 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal

Comment: No. You do not have a ‘status’. Your UK immigration history is 1 visitor visa rejection, and 1 Tier4 visa issued (subsequently curtailed when you withdrew from your studies). You can confirm this if you wish to by making a Subject Access Request https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration

Answer (score 1):

The 2018 UK visa rejection and the 2019 UK visa issuance will both remain on your record held by the UK visa authorities.

If you apply for a UK visa in the future, you must answer the questions in the application truthfully, and disclose these occurrences. UKVI will already have this information — it will be nothing new to them — but they want to know that you tell the truth. In a new application, you can explain why you left the UK early after your 2019 Tier 4 admission.

Your 2018 visa rejection did not prevent the issuance of a visa in 2019. In 2019, you obeyed the rules because there is no duty to use a visa, and no penalty for not using a visa or for departing before the visa's expiration date. Thus, these experiences should not adversely affect a future visa application.

Comment: @Hany I do not understand what you mean by "...my status will be rejected or not." What "status?" Do you have another application now pending?

Comment: @Hany You must always answer the questions in visa applications truthfully, because visa-issuing authorities in many countries share information, and the visa authority you're applying to may already know the answer. There are almost always opportunities to add information to your application, such as why you left the UK early in 2019. If you are not honest and the authorities see that you have not told the truth, your application will be denied and you may earn a years-long ban.

Comment: @Hany The US and the UK share information, as do many other countries. So our advice is always _tell the truth_. As I understand it, your UK visa application in 2018 was rejected, your UK visa application in 2019 was granted, and you entered the UK, but were forced by family circumstances to leave the UK during the term of your visa.  Tell the truth.